# Two git repositories sync between just a part of it

Tags: android, ios, git, cordova

First of all, sorry if I ask a stupid question, I'm new to git world.

I have two PhoneGap projects: one is for iOS, the other is for Android. in project structure `www` folder is common:
Android (eclipse ADT):

```
../assets/www
```

iOS (xCode):

```
../www
```

So the question is: is it possible that on the remote server I have one repo for each project and when I push with Eclipse, the content of `www` is automatically written to iOS's repo and `www` object too?

Any hint is welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are lots of ways you could solve this:

1. Sticking strictly with Git, check out [Git Submodules](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules) which allows exactly that.
2. Alternatively, if like many bigger Java-like projects, you're using dependency management, e.g. Maven / Ivy / Gradle, you could deploy an artefact (normally a JAR) of just the assets you're interested in (either from one of the projects or split the assets to a separate project), and have this as a dependency in both iOS and Android projects.
3. ...or a *really* quick-and-dirty solution is to [symlink](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link) one of the directories to the other, but this can get a bit crazy so be careful.